# Change the titleLabel of UIButton which title type is Attributed in Storyboard / Xib file

Tags: nsattributedstring

Issue :
I have use below code to change Title and set underline of UIButton at run time.

```
[btnTemp setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I have got below  issues:

1. Underline is not showing
2. Title not change
3. Title color is display default black.

To overcome this issue I have implement below code:

```
NSDictionary *attribs = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: _btnTemp.titleLabel.textColor,
NSFontAttributeName: _btnTemp.titleLabel.font,
NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)
                              };
NSAttributedString *strAttributed = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Test" attributes:attribs];

[btnTemp setAttributedTitle:strAttributed forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Try to replace `@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)` with `@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle|NSUnderlinePatternSolid)`? Also, "Title not change" meaning that you set a different text than "Test", and "Test" is no even showing? Where is your code called? Is `_btnTemp` nil? You used after `btnTemp`. Is it the same object?

Comment: @Larme try to do code same as mine which I have provide and it is correct for me. Hope it helps you.